Delete last word in the string unless it is match a specific word
I want to delete any word in the End of the string unless it is "money"
'Hello monet' must be 'Hello '
'Hellow money' must 'Hello money'
I spent many hours and nothing happened..
'Hellow money' -replace '.*[^money]$'


please provide the script code that you have tried

It's very simple The code is one string and it doesn't work as I want:   'Hello money' -replace '.*[^money]$' If to change to 'Hello monet' it delete whole string. But I want only last word

$A = 'Hello Monet';  $A = $A.Replace('Monet',''); $A. This just an example

You misunderstood a little. I need to remove any last word except "money". For example 'Hello world' - the last word "world" should also be removed. I need regex

I told, just an example for one variable. If there are more than one, you use ForEach , -match, .EndsWith(), etc.

You could use the pattern \s(?!money$).* for single lines. See https://regex101.com/r/RBueqz/2 for details.
'Hello monet', 'Hello money' -replace '\s(?!money$).*'

# Outputs:
# Hello
# Hello money

And (?m)(?<=^\S*)\s(?!money$).* for multi-line strings. See https://regex101.com/r/e5H76U/1 for details.
@'
Hello monet
Hello money
'@ -replace '(?m)(?<=^\S*)\s(?!money$).*'


Could that be simplified to '\s(?!money$).*' with just the space, negative lookahead, and second word?

If $ represents end of line, what does the .* do after it?

@lit remove everything after the space including it

@lit the $ is within the negative lookahead, but the .* actually matches the 2nd word

Break it into two parts?  Select-string in powershell 7 highlights regex matches, so it's nice for trying out regex patterns (or regex101.com).  \w is characters in a word.  [^money]$ looks at each character by itself, like [^y]$.
'Hello monet','Hello money' |
foreach-object {
  if ( $_ -match '\Wmoney$' ) {  # non word character added
    $_ 
  }
  else {
    $_ -replace '\w*$'    
  }
}

Hello
Hello money


The OP might have to clarify an edge case - what if the last word has “money” as a suffix - e.g. “hello loadsamoney” - since the last word is not equal to “money” should it be deleted or not…

It works! Thanks. But is it possible to use regex without condition ?

Maybe they don't understand me. I always have one line, the content just changes. 'Hello world' or 'Hello money' or 'Hello everyone'

I'm tring now somethimg like this and it doesn't work :)  'Hello monet' -replace '(Hello)\s+(!(money))','$1'

I need to somehow use negative but I can’t figure out how

ok, answering your first question - there is possible  the last word may contain suffix

if you need additional conditions, perhaps you should edit the questions
